# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting error to view `result_array`, please help me to get this view.

Model:

```
public function raw_attendance_Status() {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('attnDate');
        $this->db->from('tbl_attendance');
        $this->db->order_by('attnDate');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function rawAttendance(){
        $data['Dates'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_Status();
        $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
    }
```

View:

```
foreach ($Dates as $k=>$v) {
        $dates[$k] = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($v));
    }
    $heads = "<table border='1'>\n";
    $heads .= "<tr><th>TraineeID</th><th>" . join('</th><th>', $dates) . "</th></tr>\n";
$tdata .= "</table\n";
```

**$dates variable output:** 
`array(13) { [0]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-11-25" } [1]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-11-29" } [2]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-11-30" } [3]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-01" } [4]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-02" } [5]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-03" } [6]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-05" } [7]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-06" } [8]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-07" } [9]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-08" } [10]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-09" } [11]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-10" } [12]=> array(1) { ["attnDate"]=> string(10) "2015-12-12" } }`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure attnDate field is date type?
because this error

> strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

show when you use other type or your value is null
  in view print $Dates and show me results

Comment: I added the output, please take a look.

Comment: use 'attnDate' instead of 'date_column_name'

Answer (score 1):

Since your result is returning in multi dimensional array use:

```
$dates[] = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($v['attnDate']));
```

instead of:

```
$dates[] = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($v));
```

Comment: undefined index: `date_column_name`.

Comment: use: print_r($v); it will show all cloumns becuase $v is in array

Comment: please do not forget to vote up if answer is correct